# How to change the media key sound volume step count from 1% to 0.05%?

Tags: windows-7, audio, volume-mixer

My keyboard has volume up and down keys, however whenever I hit one of the keys the volume goes up/down by 1%. That's way too much in my case/hardware/equipment setup.

Is it possible to change the value which is added/decreased by these media keys?

If yes, how?

I have a program called [Volumouse](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/volumouse.html) which is able to do this, but it does not work for full screen applications (and it requires me to run an extra process in Windows) and I cannot assign my media buttons to it, only something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+Mouse wheel up/down. I don't like that (especially when I have media keys for that).

Comment: +1 for using Volumouse, my favorite software for stuff like this. But my volumouse also works in games and other fullscreen applications. You have to use *Custom keys are pressed*. You will not see the indicator bar, but it will de/increase the volume

Comment: can I somehow remap volumouse to use my media keys?

Comment: It doesn't detect them in the "Hot keys: Increase and Hot keys: Decrease" fields when I press my media keys

Comment: Yeah, I could reproduce that. Maybe you can remap those media keys to a standard key function? Just a thought. I did a quick test with [sharpkeys](http://www.randyrants.com/2011/12/sharpkeys_35.html) without luck

Comment: as a gamer I have to reject that suggestion : ( most keys are already used for many purposes :$ (including home, pg up, pg down, scrl lck, `, even num lock (because num lock is always ON with NumLocker) and caps (also always turned off by NumLocker))

Comment: Which KB make/model is this? If it comes with software that can help you modify the functionality of the multimedia keys, you might be able to use it to launch a script or command that changes the volume. Else try the workaround I posted below.

Comment: the keyboard is a default Acer 5742G build in laptop keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Download and extract [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) to for example C:\
2. Save the following as a .REG file and import it (confirm that the keys were added to the registry):

   > Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
   >
   > [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AppKey\10] "ShellExecute"="C:\\Nircmd.exe changesysvolume 1"
   >
   > [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AppKey\9]
   >   "ShellExecute"="C:\\Nircmd.exe changesysvolume -1"
3. Press the **Volume Up** and **Volume Down** multimedia keys on your keyboard and see if the system volume changes in small increments.

Note 1: The **AppKey** values for **APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP** (10) and **APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN** (9) were obtained from [here](http://ashish.vashisht.net/2008/01/configuring-keyboard-multimedia-keys.html).

Note 2: A single unit change might be too small to hear any difference. In that case, change the commands above to increase/decrease the volume by 500 or 1000 units at a time (the max. value is 65535).

Note 3: NirCmd supports many other volume related functions, which you can read about in detail [here](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd2.html).

Comment: if I have x64 don't I need it to place in `wow64node`?

Comment: The location was copied from my Win7 x64 registry, so it should work. Edit: Actually, I see that `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\explorer\AppKey` exists as well, so perhaps you should make identical changes in *both* locations, just to be sure.

Comment: I did that and somehow i restarted the sysmen and whenether I hit the VOL_UP or VOL_DOWN key the volume changes by 2%, removed those registry entries, reboot, still the same! :O I don't know what's happening :/ (or well why it doesn't work). I tried running the commands from the command prompt (the ones from the reg) and then it does work, so somehow the keys aren't replaced..

Comment: I have verified and the keys exist with the right values

Comment: You added the keys in both locations, right? Maybe your KB uses different AppCommands... Do the ones that *already* existed under `AppKey` work properly?

Comment: yes in both locations, I have only Play/Pause key, STOP, Forward, Backward, Volume up, Volume down, brighness up, brightness down, wifi on/off, black screen, dmute, switch display output and sleep, all of them work but none of them is in \AppKeys\ .. :o

Comment: Since this is a laptop KB and not a standalone desktop KB, maybe it's doing some weird proprietary stuff inside.

Comment: is there an application to detect which commands the keyboard sends? :$

Comment: Yes, the article I found the AppCommand values in links to a program that can detect multimedia keys. I just tested TestAppCommands6.exe by selecting the options for Volume Up/Down/Mute, and it was able to detect the keys just fine (although I use a USB desktop keyboard).