# How to improve audio manipulation with Windows 7 that is broken?

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, sony-vaio

When I try to control the audio in Windows 7, it is giving me problems. When I use the function key with the audio up or audio down (F4 and F3 keys) then pressing those keys blackenens the screen and has the eventual effect of turning the sound up too much and down too much. The behavior is somewhat unpredictable but trying to use the function keys for the sound is not working the way it should. It is a sony vaio VPC5A. Can you help me?

For instance, I'd like to be able to go to myspace and start the player with an audioclip playing and then use the function keys to control the strength of audio but it is not working the way it should.

### Update

Now after some reboots, it does pass a functional test so the previous problem might've been due to experimental usage from my part.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a hardware issue you'll obviously need to get the keyboard looked at and possibly replaced. Otherwise try uninstalling and reinstalling the audio driver/software as well as any other Sony preinstalled software that's responsible for keyboard shortcuts.

An alternative solution you can use is [Volumouse](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/volumouse.html), which will allow you to use your mousewheel (if you have one) to control system or per-app volume easily:

[image: 1]

You can also set up keyboard shortcuts to call [NirCmd](https://superuser.com/a/529125/138343) to increase/decrease system volume in small increments.