# Change magnitude of volume change with keyboard media controls

Tags: windows-7, audio, keyboard

My keyboard has volume buttons on it. When I use them with my Windows 7 laptop, they increase/decrease the volume by 2 points (i.e. if I'm at 2% volume and I press the volume up key, it will go to 4% volume). I'd like finer control, so I'd like to change this to a 1 point change. Is this possible?

Comment: why do you want such precise change ?

Comment: Because just now while wearing my headphones and listening to music, 2% was too quiet and 4% was too loud.

Comment: I have never found a built-in way to change this, but there is a workaround.  If you lower the volume of individual media programs to 50% of the main volume control (click the volume icon and click "Mixer" to do this), then each 2% change of the main volume will translate to a 1% change in your media player.  I actually usually keep my media player volume at 25% of the total, so each 2% change in the main volume is a 0.5% change in the media player.

Comment: Also see [here](http://superuser.com/a/588153/138343).